# SSH connections rejected after UFW allow 22

Tags: 12.04, networking, server, firewall, ufw

I am trying to setup UFW on a 12.04 server.

SSH works great with UFW off.

Setting

```
root@ugvps:~# ufw enable 
Firewall is active and enabled on system startup
root@ugvps:~# ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere
```

The server now refuses all connections to 22 and the following appears in the log

```
Jul  8 15:12:49 ugvps kernel: [445929.928075] [UFW BLOCK] IN=venet0 OUT= MAC= SRC=217.86.198.115 DST=MY.SERV.ERI.Pxx LEN=48 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=118 ID=14040 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=48965 DPT=22 WINDOW=8192 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

What have I done wrong?
Thanks

Edit:  This is running inside an OpenVZ container if that matters.  I've followed [this guide](http://blog.bodhizazen.com/linux/how-to-use-ufw-in-openvz-templates/) to get ufw running in the first place

Comment: Are you sure the ssh is running and configure for that port?

Comment: What does runnining  `nmap` on the IP address say?

Comment: @ Bruno Pereira: Yes, because running ufw disable makes SSH immediately work again.

Comment: @Anders see this paste with results. http://pastebin.com/7xdrRcxs Essentially, once I run ufw enable, everything is blocked.  Otherwise, 22 and 80 are open

Comment: You might want to look at this with 'iptable' command to see what rules is built by ufw actually does when you start.